# WPF dynamic panel creation in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating an editor for an object instance hierarchy. The editor has a panel whose child controls vary depending on the fields of the object. So for type A which has an integer field it will have a spinner control; for type B which has a string field it will have a TextBox. And so on.

Question is, how do you achieve this in MVVM?

Comment: I don't understand what you're stuck on, you simply check the type of fields and create the elements in the code accordingly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum do I do this in code-behind? It's straightforward in "normal" C#, but in MVVM I can't be writing stuff like "new TextBox()" in the ViewModel.

Comment: Of course you can be writing stuff like `new Grid` and appending it, very much like you can in every other GUI environment :) I'd use XAML for the most part and only generate the dynamic element in C# code behind. Note that MVVM describes how you separate concerns between the presentation and business logic - not how you build the template :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ContentControl` in your XAML code nad bind to some type (event system types - what you want):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourProperty}"/>
```

(YourProperty is a Property from you ViewModel attached to view)

then you have to create DataTemplate that render view:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:int}">
    <views:MyWindow/>
</DataTemplate>
```

system and views are namespaces in you xaml code. In this example I use system:int type, but it can be your custom type. `MyWindow` is an `UserControl` object - so you basically create another WPF `UserControl` file in your solution.

It works like this. `ContentControl` gets its `Content` and check it's type. It looks for `DataTemplate` that can cast this type to some `View` (it can be text, textbox, ect) that can be rendered as a `Content`.

Best regards

Comment: +1 Its worth adding, using a DataTemplateSelector this can be even further customized, for example if a different Template is necessary depending on a value of a property in the View Model.